# mysql/innodb deadlock on simple delete query

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

mysql/innodb, repeatable read transaction, deadlock on deletion of non intercepting rows. Trying to understand what is happening.

```
    ------------------------
    LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
    ------------------------
    2019-05-08 06:16:23 7f4a5769a700
    *** (1) TRANSACTION:
    TRANSACTION 12314813, ACTIVE 1 sec fetching rows
    mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
    LOCK WAIT 13 lock struct(s), heap size 2936, 355 row lock(s), undo log entries 110
    MySQL thread id 1654182, OS thread handle 0x7f4a57658700, query id 21892885 xx.xx.xx.xx oc5z updating
    DELETE FROM deal_product_rows_tmp WHERE batch_no=5754
    *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
    RECORD LOCKS space id 219 page no 3 n bits 168 index `PRIMARY` of table `db1`.`deal_product_rows_tmp` trx id 12314813 lock_mode X waiting
    Record lock, heap no 88 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 11; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 4; hex 80001bb9; asc     ;;
     1: len 6; hex 000000bbe8c0; asc       ;;
     2: len 7; hex be000001b50110; asc        ;;
     3: len 4; hex 8000167b; asc    {;;
     4: len 4; hex 800fe7c4; asc     ;;
     5: len 4; hex 80002516; asc   % ;;
     6: len 4; hex 8000986e; asc    n;;
     7: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
     8: len 30; hex 415254455820d184d0bed180d0bcd18b20d0bfd180d18fd0bcd0bed183d0; asc PROD                        ; (total 81 bytes);
     9: len 8; hex 0000000000208c40; asc        @;;
     10: len 1; hex 4d; asc M;;

    *** (2) TRANSACTION:
    TRANSACTION 12314816, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
    mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
    14 lock struct(s), heap size 2936, 95 row lock(s), undo log entries 14
    MySQL thread id 1654175, OS thread handle 0x7f4a5769a700, query id 21892888 xx.xx.xx.xx oc5z updating
    DELETE FROM deal_product_rows_tmp WHERE batch_no=5755
    *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
    RECORD LOCKS space id 219 page no 3 n bits 168 index `PRIMARY` of table `db1`.`deal_product_rows_tmp` trx id 12314816 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
    Record lock, heap no 25 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 11; compact format; info bits 0
```

Table structure:

```
     CREATE TABLE `deal_product_rows_tmp` (
      `batch_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `bitrix_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `deal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `product_name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
      `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
      `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `tmp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY (`tmp_id`),
      KEY `idx_deal_row_tmp_deal` (`deal_id`),
      KEY `idx_deal_row_tmp_batchno` (`batch_no`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7500 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Did I understand correctly: first transaction trying to apply gap lock on all rows at index page. one by one record (Next-Key Locks). Second transaction trying the same, but in different direction. In result part of index page locked by transaction 1, part by transaction 2.
I'm understand that I can reduce transaction isolation level to RC, I'm trying to understand how the repeatable read works in innodb.

UPDATE: same situation with Read Committed IL.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE deal_product_rows_tmp` would help. Generally http://dba.stackexchange.com/ is a better DBA forum for this sort of question.

Comment: Table structure added

Comment: The ranges appear to be next to each other?  This may be a case where InnoDB would have to work too hard to avoid a deadlock, so it punted.  Moral of the story: Catch deadlocks and be ready to replay the transaction.

Comment: Yes, I can replay, but I still do not understand how it can be possible. I've reproduced the issue on simple test case here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238756/mysql-innodb-trying-to-lock-uncommitted-row-from-parallel-transaction-deadlock